# build new element using jquery, missing closing "/"

Tags: jquery, syntax

I would like to have a up-side down triangle for my input value. But we I build my input element like this, it just prints out the value instead of having a up-side down triangle.

The code generated in the browser is:

```
<input class="someclass" type="button" value="&#9662;">
```

from this code:

```
  var arrow_input = jq('<input/>',{ 
                      class:"someclass", 
                      type :"button", 
                      value:"&#9662;"   
                    });
```

I noticed it's missing the closing "/"  but if I am using jquery to construct this element, how do add the missing closing /"? Thanks!

Comment: You don't. The closing `/` is optional and the browser determines whether or not to include it, not jQuery.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use that syntax to create inputs, some versions of IE don't play very well with setting the `type` attribute after creating an input. This is noted in the documentation.

Comment: and `class` is a reserved word.